# Functors with multiple arguments in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

I've the following situation:

```
module type M = sig type s = ...  end

module Make(P: Something) : (M with type s = P.t) = struct
   type s = P.t
   ...
end
```

that works fine to generate modules of `M` type that use specific implementation of modules of type `Something` inside their implementation.

Now suppose I have another module defined as

```
module type AU = sig
  val feed : float -> unitv
  val nth : int -> (float -> float)
  val reset : unit -> unit
end
```

that has various implementations

```
module SUAlg : AU = struct ... end
module MLAlg : AU = struct ... end
module ACEAlg : AU = struct ... end
```

The point of the question is that the `M` module should be parametrized over two things now: a `Something` module and a `AU` module so that it's something like

```
module Make(P: Something) : (M with type s = P.t) = struct
   type s = P.t
   module Alg = MLAlg (* just an example *)
   ...
end
```

but I would like to have a generic functor that given a `Something` and given an `AU` it produces a module with both things concretized. Is there a way to obtain that easily?

Since functor syntax is quite strange and I'm still new to it I don't know if what I'm asking can be solved in a simple way or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, a functor can have several arguments. The syntax is like this:

```
module Make_LOffset
            (V:Lattice_With_Isotropy.S)
            (LOffset : Offsetmap.S with type y = V.t and type widen_hint = V.widen_hint) =
struct
   …
end
```

The functor can then be applied with `Make_LOffset(V)(LOffset)`.

In this example, taken from existing code to ensure it is syntactically correct, `Make_LOffset` is parameterized by two modules `V` and `LOffset`, of respective signatures `Lattice_With_Isotropy.S` and `Offsetmap.S`. There are additional type constraints between the two signatures, the `with type … and type …` part.

Comment: Is there a different syntax for passing arguments into the functor? Make_LOffset(arg1 arg2)?

Comment: @stumped Well the arguments would be module, so they would look like `Arg1` and `Arg2`. The syntax is  `Make_LOffset(Arg1)(Arg2)`. I have updated the answer.